# How to fetch from a jquery datatable an array of second colum cells subject to checkbox in first column

Tags: java, jquery, html

I have a table as follows

```
<table id="vainTbl6" class="dtable" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>check</td><th>Morphosal</th><th>goat </th><th>the other</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbdy">
         <tr class="gradeX">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" /></td>
            <td style="width:55%">-Approve the femuneration Gommiqee purpirt</td>
            <td>pontpose</td></tr>
       <tr class="gradeX">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" /></td>
            <td style="width:55%">-Declare a final truce</td>
            <td>More</td></tr>
       <tr class="gradeX"><td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" /></td>
            <td style="width:55%">-Amend the articles of asscotonation</td>
            <td>Four</td></tr>
       <tr class="gradeX"><td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" /></td>
            <td style="width:55%">-Re-elect Bandanna la banana for warden</td>
            <td>Floor</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the first column is a checkbox.  I need to fetch all the second column cells where the checkbox in the first column is set to true

I tried using this, but to no avail.

```
  function extractRowCell(divNode){
    alert(divNode.id);
    $('#tbdy tr td').each(function() {    
     alert('hello');
     var aRowData = this.cells
     alert(aRowData[1].firstChild.value);
             return aRowData;
     });
}
```

The call is as follows:

```
 <a id="la" href='#' onclick='extractRowCell(this.parentNode)' style="position:absolute; top:280px; left:350px;">Votes & Concerns</a>
```

The alert in the function triggers though with the correct value.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate over the `td's` simply do the following.

```
$('#tbdy tr td').each(function() {    
     alert( $(this).text() ); 
});
```

Comment: Your code is not working for me...And that would be just one row?  right?  Perhaps that I should do this first    $('#tbdy tr').each(function() {    
     alert( $(this).childNodes[1].text() ); 
});

Comment: That would be all rows and all td's. Yes there's many ways to do it. With your code you could then do `$(this).find('td').each(function(){ alert( $(this).text() ) })`

Comment: Wow, I must apologize.  It does work.  For some reason the browser does not refresh completely, at times!  I see how that works.  The only other thing is to figure out when the checkbox is 'true'  So, thank you for the code. It works fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<table><tbody id="tbdy">
<tr class="gradeX">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" /></td>
            <td style="width:55%" class="item">-Approve the femuneration Gommiqee purpirt</td>
            <td>pontpose</td></tr>
       <tr class="gradeX">
            <td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" /></td>
            <td style="width:55%" class="item">-Declare a final truce</td>
            <td>More</td></tr>
       <tr class="gradeX"><td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" /></td>
            <td style="width:55%" class="item">-Amend the articles of asscotonation</td>
            <td>Four</td></tr>
       <tr class="gradeX"><td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" /></td>
            <td style="width:55%"  class="item">-Re-elect Bandanna la banana for warden</td>
            <td>Floor</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button>Get</button>
<script>
    $("button").click(function(){
    var ret="";
    $("#tbdy tr td:first").each(function()
    {
    if($("input:checked").length!=0)
    {       
        ret=$("input:checked").parent().parent().find("td.item").text();

    }       
    });
    alert(ret);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you.  This addresses the checkbox.  Will try it though I cannot use the onclick event there.  If user changes his mind and unclicks...